# Declaring a fixed-length padded string in GNU assembler

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu

I'm trying to define some data in a fixed-size structure in assembler. I'd like to declare string data of a fixed number of bytes, initialised with a string. In C it would be:

```
char my_string[32] = "hello";
```

Which is 32 bytes, and padded with however many zeros needed at the end.

What would be the equivalent in assembler? I know I can manually count the length of my string and declare the necessary number of zero bytes to pad to 32, e.g.:

```
my_string:
  .asciz "hello"
  .zero 26
```

But how can I do it if the string is being defined dynamically, such as from an external define or include?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I'd use a macro with local labels for this.  For example:

```
    .macro padded_string string, max
1:
    .ascii "\string"
2:
    .iflt \max - (2b - 1b)
    .error "String too long"
    .endif

    .ifgt \max - (2b - 1b)
    .zero \max - (2b - 1b)
    .endif

    .endm
```

...used like this:

```
my_string:
    padded_string "Hello world!", 16
```

(This has C-like behaviour of not adding the terminating 0 if the string is exactly `max` characters long.  To ensure the string is terminated, just change the `.ascii` to `.asciz`.)

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is still a static string, albeit of unknown size. You can get the size of the string my subtracting the address of the string from current data pointer ($). Subtract the size of the string from the maximum size and you know how many zeroes to add:

```
my_string:
    .ascii "mystery string"
    .zero (maxsize-($-my_string)) ;maxsize-actualsize
```

which can be simplified to:

```
my_string:
    .ascii "mystery string"
    .zero (maxsize+my_string-$)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, when I try it, I get the message "Error: .space specifies non-absolute value".

Comment: `.` works better than `$`, for ARM at least.  This is one of those areas where `gas` syntax varies across different target platforms...

Answer (score 0):

I would have preferred [Jens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931650/declaring-a-fixed-length-padded-string-in-gnu-assembler/4933198#4933198) of using e.g. `.zero (32+my_string-$)`, however I got the error message `Error: .space specifies non-absolute value`.

This seems to be a viable alternative:

```
my_string:
  .asciz "mystery string"
  .org my_string + 32
other_stuff:
  ...
```

I don't know if it guarantees that the whole 32 bytes are set to particular values (i.e. trailing bytes filled with zeros), but using `.asciz` does ensure the string is zero-terminated.